# MongoDB Query taking too long for a single document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This question might duplicate, but I have not found an answer on SO or even Googling for it.

I have a quite simple mongodb database, where I store `agents` that are simply defined by `{__id, username, __system}` and some other properties (nothing too wild, and almost no nesting). I have created both indexes for `__id` and `username` (note the double underscore on __id).

Right now, I have a single docuemnt on `agents`, and querying `{username: 'jo', __system: 'test_system'}` takes 210ms on average.

I can't find the problem since a single document should be way faster to read and indexes are present on the db.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you give some information about size of your collections ? And can you post explain result of your query https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/ ?

Comment: How are you measuring? It could be you're taking the wrong times here. Is there a network in between your MongoDB server and the client?

Comment: Could be I/O latency (disk / network)? Are you doing this on localhost or remotely? If remotely you have to keep in mind that it requires at least 1 roundtrips to fetch the document... if the connection needs to be established first then it takes at least 2 roundtrips meaning if you have a 50ms ping to your target you'll easily get 200ms response time to just to query one single document.

Comment: 1) There is a network between mongo and app (I'm using mongodb atlas), however: Using explain returns 0 millis every time
2) Using Compass returns 0 millis as well
3) I'm testing timing like so:

`
let now = Date.now();
db.collection('agents').findOne({username: 'jo', __system: 'test_system'}).then(agent => {
    console.log('REQUEST TIME', Date.now() - now);
}).catch(e => {});
`

Otherwise, this is the only request performed on my API endpoint (localhost),which responds in 300ms according to Postman (=> 80ms for treating the request )

Comment: @KhánhBùiĐức my [`explain` output here](https://pastebin.com/YFaYnt2f), thanks!

Comment: My servers were in the USA (i'm in france), switching them to Frankfurt did help, however the request still takes 80ms, while ping to the server 20ms, and treating the data 0ms (I log the time on the request directly)...
I'm out of ideas